# Prove: Cauchy Product

Tags: real-analysis

Prove: If $\sum{|a_n|} < \infty$ and $\sum{b_n}$ converges (perhaps conditionally), with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}=A$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{b_n}=B$, then the Cauchy Product
$\sum{c_n}$= $(\sum{a_n})$$(\sum{b_n})$ converges to $AB$.

I have a general outline of the proof: I would let $\{A_n\}$, $\{B_n\}$, $\{C_n\}$ be the partial sums of the series. And would show that $C_n - A_nB=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{a_r(B_{n-r} - B)}$ and then would apply Cauchy's Convergence Criterion for Series to $\sum{|a_n|}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Split the sum for $C_n-A_nB$ into two parts, according to whether $r$ is "small" or not.

Comment: Are we to assume that $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ converge to A and B?

Comment: @user65384 Yes, you are to assume they converge to A and B respectively.

Answer (score 1):

See theorem 3.50 page 74 in [Baby Rudin](http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/instructors/ozturk/eskiders/guz12m331/rud.pdf).